# Why when pausing the game it keep showing the game play canvas text on screen when it's loading the main menu scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ScenesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<UnityEngine.Object> sceneAssets = new List<Object>();

    private static UnityEngine.Object MainMenuScene;
    private static UnityEngine.Object TheGamePlayScene;
    private static bool InMainMenu = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (UnityEngine.Object sceneasset in sceneAssets)
        {
            if (sceneasset.name == "Main Menu")
            {
                MainMenuScene = sceneasset;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneasset.name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            }
            else
            {
                TheGamePlayScene = sceneasset;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StartNewGame()
    {
        if (InMainMenu == true)
        {
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(TheGamePlayScene.name);
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene(TheGamePlayScene.name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(MainMenuScene.name);
    }

    public static void BackToMainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(MainMenuScene.name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        InMainMenu = true;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public static void ResumeGame()
    {
        SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(MainMenuScene.name);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
}
```

When getting back to the main menu after starting a new game I keep both the MainMenuScene and GamePlayScene at the same time in the Hierarchy this way I can pause the game and resume the game.

The problem is that when both scenes in the Hierarchy it's showing both main menu and the gameplay scenes canvas texts. And I don't want to disable any gamesobjects or canvas in the GamePlayScene.

Is there any way to avoid this text/s overlap ?

In the screenshot it's showing the problem :

[image: Overlap]

BTW : I saw now another problem. When I hit the escape key and it's pausing the game when the main menu scene is loaded about second or two after that the NAVI and the yellow text show. It seems like for a second or two it kept going on the game and didn't pause immediately. I can't figure out why.

Comment: I don't get why you use your main menu scene as a pause menu, why don't you just create a canvas for pausing that you enable and disable as you wish ? Isn't that just simpler ?

Comment: @AnisBrachemi You mean to separate the pausing section from the main menu ? To add a canvas to the game scene and this canvas will have pause/resume buttons and will do the pause ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant